# What is the meaning of Copy_X in sklearn linear models

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Can someone explain what is the meaning of **Copy_X** in sklearn linear models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [documentation for Linear Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression), the following is provided:

```
copy_X : boolean, optional, default True
If True, X will be copied; else, it may be overwritten.
```

The input X, when you try to fit/etc the model will, if the flag is set to true (default), be copied for use within the function. This means that the original X you passed as a parameter will be the same after the fit/etc has been performed.

If you set the flag to false, there is a chance that the X you pass in will NOT be the same as it was before you ran fit/etc.

I hope this helps.

Comment: How or what determines that X gets overwritten please? For large datasets copy_x=True is not efficient